# How to change fragments in viewpager by pressing a button in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Suppose I have three fragments connected to a ViewPager and I want that whenever I press a button on one the fragments, I automatically scroll to the next fragment. I can't access the viewpager methods from the fragments. How do I do this?

Edit: Nicolas Simon's solution is working somewhat. Now I'm having a problem setting the interface on the fragments.

```
MyFragment fragment1;
fragment1.setInterface(this);
```

I'm getting an error that says Null pointer access: fragment1 can be null at only this location.

Comment: Are all buttons different? Do they have to be within the fragment or can they be placed outside?

Comment: each button is different and placed in its respective fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each button is different, you'll have to define an interface to communicate between your activity and your fragments.

```
public interface GoToNextInterface {
  void onGoToNext();
}
```

Your MainActivity will have to implement this interface and the method that goes with it :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoToNextInterface {
  //Your regular methods...
@Override
public void onGoToNext() {
  if (myAdapter != null) {
    myAdapter.setCurrentItem(myAdapter.getCurrentItem + 1);
  }
}
```

Still in your activity, set the interface on your fragments :

```
fragment1.setInterface(this);
fragment2.setInterface(this);
```

In your Fragments, add the `setInterface` method :

```
private GoToNextInterface mInterface;

public void setInterface(GoToNextInterface i) {
      mInterface = i;
}
```

And finally in each fragment, trigger the effect with :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mInterface != null) {
      mInterface.onGoToNext();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Where do I create the interface? In MainActivity or as a seperate class file?

Comment: Create a new class file for that

Comment: I'm getting this error while creating the setInterface method: void is an invalid type for the variable setInterface. I did everything as you said.

Comment: This is what I would do also! Good answer!

Comment: But it's not working. private GoToNextInterface mInterface; This line throws an error saying that private modifier cannot be used only final.

Comment: The line `private GoToNextInterface mInterface` has to be declared as a member of your fragment, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to declare it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setCurrentItem` method of the ViewPager for this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setCurrentItem(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)%22setCurrentItem(int)%22) or [setCurrentItem(int,boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) with the adapter object.

```
myAdapter.setCurrentItem(myAdapter.getCurrentItem()+1)
```

or

```
myAdapter.setCurrentItem(myAdapter.getCurrentItem()-1)
```

Make sure that `myAdapter.getCurrentItem()` should be greater than 0 and less than item count.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, it would have been more simpler if you would have included your ViewPager code where you setting it up.

Anyway you need to make that method public where you setting the `ViewPager` in `MainActivity` of fragment and then set the current page for `ViewPager`,

here is an example

```
//SUPPOSE THIS IS THE METHOD YOUR USING TO SETUP FRAGMENT VIEWPAGER
public void setupViewPager(int pageNumber) {

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(), "First Fragment");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(), "Second Fragment");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);
}
```

Then from fragment you can call it through interface which is a better way and also you can call it directly like this

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).setupViewPager(1) // Here you can give the number of fragment you want to go to starting from 0.
```

Hope it helps